# Criteria for convergence in $L^1$ for sigma finite measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure and $(f_n)_{n\geq1}$ and $f$ be measurable functions. Show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\mu)$
iff all of the following three conditions are satisfied

1. $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure.
2. The sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable, i.e.
   $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that if $\mu(E) < δ$ then $\int_E |f_n(x)| d\mu(x) < \epsilon$ for any $n$.
3. The sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly tight, i.e.
   $\forall\epsilon > 0, \exists E, \mu(E) < \infty$ such that for any $n$ :
   $\int_{E^c} |f_n(x)| d\mu(x) < \epsilon$.

Remark: If $\mu$ is finite, the last condition is automatically satisfied

Remark: I am able to show the first two parts of implication, I am unable to show that $F_n$ converging in $L^1$ implies uniform tightness; also I am unable to show that given the three conditions are satisfied the sequence of measurable functions converge in $L^1$.

Comment: Which parts exactly can you prove? Do you mean that you're having trouble proving that $f_n$ converging in $L^1$ implies the three conditions?

Comment: no the other way round.

Comment: The other way is a variant of the Vitali convergence theorem. Do you know what to do when you replace convergence in measure with a.e. convergence?

Comment: Thanks. Nopes, I do not not know what to do in such a case.

Comment: To prove the uniform tightness, first take some $E$ of finite measure so that $\int_{E^c} |f(x)|d\mu(x)$ is small. Then take some $n_0$ so that for all $n\ge n_0$, $\int|f_n(x) - f(x)|d\mu(x)$ is small. Argue that then $\int_{E^c} |f_n(x)|d\mu(x)$ must be small too. Finally, if needed, "increase $E$ to let small values of $n$ in". Report if you have some problems with this approach.

Comment: In the case with a.e. convergence you can find the proof in textbooks, e.g. Royden and Fitzpatrick. The case with convergence in measure is usually then given as an exercise (the proof is quite similar).